# My get returns empty even when I fill it?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to this site but I got a problem with my code.

I started with OOP in PHP and I'm struggling with get and set.

I'm filling my set with a value but when I request it in a other class I can't get the value.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $row) {
                $invoice->setInvoiceBeginDate($row['beginDatum']);
                $invoice->setInvoiceEndDate($row['eindDatum']);
                $invoice->setDeliveryLocation($row['locatie']);
                $invoice->insertInvoice();
                $invoice->setLastInsertedInvoice_ID($invoice->sqlSelect("invoice_ID", "invoice", "", "","","1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));
                $invoice->setCarId($row['car']);

                //here is where the error is coming from
                if ($order->insertOrder()) {

                    $status = 1;

                } else {

                    $status = 0;

                    $invoice->deleteInvoice();
                }
            }
```

and my 2 classes:

```
class Invoice extends DynamicSql
{

private $invoiceBeginDate;
private $invoiceEndDate;
private $deliveryLocation;
private $invoiceId;
private $lastInsertedId;
private $carId;

public function insertInvoice()
{

    if ($this->sqlInsert(
        "invoice",
        array(
            "invoiceBeginDate" => $this->getInvoiceBeginDate(),
            "invoiceEndDate" => $this->getInvoiceEndDate(),
            "deliveryLocation" => $this->getDeliveryLocation()
        )
    )) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}

public function deleteInvoice()
{

    if($this->sqlDelete(
        "invoice",
        array(
            ["invoice_ID" => $this->getLastInsertedInvoice_ID()]
        )
    ))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

public function setInvoiceBeginDate($value){
    $this->invoiceBeginDate = $value;
}

public function getInvoiceBeginDate(){
    return $this->invoiceBeginDate;
}

public function setInvoiceEndDate($value){
    $this->invoiceEndDate = $value;
}

public function getInvoiceEndDate(){
    return $this->invoiceEndDate;
}

public function setDeliveryLocation($value){
    $this->deliveryLocation = $value;
}

public function getDeliveryLocation(){
    return $this->deliveryLocation;
}

public function setInvoiceId($value){
    $this->invoiceId = $value;
}

public function getInvoiceId(){
    return $this->invoiceId;
}

public function setLastInsertedInvoice_ID($value){
    $this->lastInsertedId = $value;
}

public function getLastInsertedInvoice_ID(){
    return $this->lastInsertedId;
}

public function setCarId($value){
    $this->carId = $value;
}

public function getCarId(){
    return $this->carId;
}

}

class Order extends Invoice {

public function insertOrder() {

    echo $this->getLastInsertedInvoice_ID(), $_SESSION['user_session'], $this->getCarId();

    $this->sqlInsert("orders",
        array(
            "invoiceId" => $this->getLastInsertedInvoice_ID(),
            "user_ID" => $_SESSION['user_session'],
            "carId" => $this->getCarId()
        )
    );

}


}
```

And here is my error that invoiceId is empty:

> 27 (the 27 is from the $_SESSION['user_session'] other 2 are not set
> for some reason) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with
> message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
> 'invoiceId' cannot be null' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\TestExame\includes\sqlQuery.php:177 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\TestExame\includes\sqlQuery.php(177):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\TestExame\includes\sqlQuery.php(662):
> DynamicSql->sqlInsert('orders', Array) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\TestExame\cart.php(54): Order->insertOrder() #3 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestExame\includes\sqlQuery.php on line 177

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: What you are getting in `getLastInsertedInvoice_ID()` ?

Comment: my last inserted invoice id that i set just before i call $order->insertOrder().

the weird thing is that it doesn't set it.

i tested it and invoiceId and carId both have a value.

Comment: Check by this `"invoiceId" => $this->getLastInsertedInvoice_ID()?:'1000',` what you get stored in your db? `last id` or `1000` ?

Comment: then 1000 is being inserted into my database

Comment: it means your are not getting value in `$this->getLastInsertedInvoice_ID()`